# How to return max value from array object in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

i have array like this :

[image]

how to return status title from the largest id (not status.id) from that array in angular?

i have changed my code like this :

```
getData(id){
    let url_detail = this.apiurl + `/${id}`;
    this.http.get<any[]>(url_detail).pipe(
        tap(data=>{
            var status = data.reduce((item, curr) => {
                return item.id < curr.id ? curr : item;
              }).status.title;
        
            return status;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

when i call that function like this :

```
console.log("status ", this.service.getData(1))
```

it just returns undefined.
Please help me.

Comment: `o.status` is an object - you want `return o.status.id`

Comment: Which largest id are you refering to? id of object inside array or inside status?

Comment: i want to return status.title from the largest id of that array @MdJunaidAlam

Comment: largest `id` or `status.id`?

Comment: largest id @dork

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alma, `tap` does NOT change the response, use `map` instead. Futhermore, you need subscribe to the Observable which is returned by HttpClient.get to retrieve a result. This combined with the answer of @dork

```
getData(id){
    let url_detail = this.apiurl + `/${id}`;
    <!--see that you use return-->
    return this.http.get<any[]>(url_detail).pipe(
        <!--see that use map-->
        map(data=>{
            var status = data.reduce((item, curr) => {
                return item.id < curr.id ? curr : item;
              }).status.title;
        
            return status;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}

//and
this.service.getData(1).susbcribe(res=>{
   console.log("status ", res)
})
```

Comment: sorry, I missed the "return" `return this.http.get(...)`, see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method of arrays for this to get the object with the largest `id` and then get that object's `status.title`.

```
data.reduce((item, curr) => {
  return item.id < curr.id ? curr : item;
}).status.title;
```